# Android MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview

Please help me out, I am working on a Project Xyz having the mapView with add multiple overlays and remove overlays as per userChoice.

To be more clear it filters the overlays as per user choice,,,,

Suppose showing favorite places, friends of a user...

PostLoginServiceHomeBean is my ArrayList with an ArrayList NearByFavoritePlacesList object

**entry.getNearByFavoritePlacesList().get(i).getGpsLatitude()
                            .trim()**

i.e by this i'm getting the multiple lat long form server...

The code runs f9 and add the multiple overlays to my map and shows name and address of repective place on overlay tap.But how could I remove the overlays form my map...

I am enclosing the code:Please find the code below:

Please help me out....

```
package com.gogozing.app;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.gogozing.service.LocateServices;
import com.gogozing.util.Data;
import com.gogozing.util.PostLoginServiceHomeBean;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class HomeMapActivity extends MapActivity {
    private MapView myMapView;
    private MapController myMapController;
    private List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
    private HomeMapItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay;
    private Context context;
    private PostLoginServiceHomeBean entry;
    private GeoPoint initGeoPoint;
    private CheckBox peopleCheckBox, friendsCheckBox, favoritesCheckBox;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_map_layout);
        context = this;
        backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HomeMapLeftBackButton);
        eventsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.EventsBtn);
        profileBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ProflieBtn);
        homeBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HomeBtn);
        locateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LocateBtn);
        socializeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SocializeBtn);
        peopleCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.HomeMapViewPeopleCheckBox);
        favoritesCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.HomeMapViewFavoritesCheckBox);
        friendsCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.HomeMapViewFriendsCheckBox);


        homeBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_f);
        myMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapviewHome);


        myMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        // Set satellite view
        myMapController = myMapView.getController();

        // Get the current location in start-up
        try {

            entry = Data.postLoginServiceHomeMain.get(0);

            favoritesCheckBox
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                boolean isChecked) {
                            if (isChecked) {
                                viewFavoritePlaces();
                            } else
                                removeFavoritePlaces();

                        }
                    });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(Data.LOG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    void viewFavoritePlaces() {
        for (int i = 0; i < entry.getNearByFavoritePlacesList().size(); i++) {
            double latitude = Double.valueOf(
                    **entry.getNearByFavoritePlacesList().get(i).getGpsLatitude()
                            .trim()**).doubleValue();
            double longitude = Double.valueOf(
                    entry.getNearByFavoritePlacesList().get(i)
                            .getGpsLongitude().trim()).doubleValue();
            Log.v(Data.LOG1, " Latitude " + latitude + " Longitude "
                    + longitude);

            String name = entry.getNearByFavoritePlacesList().get(i)
                    .getMerchantName();
            String address = entry.getNearByFavoritePlacesList().get(i)
                    .getAddress();
            initGeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1E6),
                    (int) (longitude * 1E6));

            mapOverlays = myMapView.getOverlays();
            Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.map_store_place);

            itemizedOverlay = new HomeMapItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);
            OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(initGeoPoint, name,
                    address);

            itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);

            mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
            myMapController.animateTo(initGeoPoint);
            myMapController.setZoom(15);
        }
    }
    void removeFavoritePlaces() {
        //List<Overlay> mapOverlays = myMapView.getOverlays();

        mapOverlays.remove(itemizedOverlay);

    }



    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    };

    public class HomeMapItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
        private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        private Context mContext;

        public HomeMapItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
            super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
            mContext = context;
        }

        public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
            mOverlays.add(overlay);
            populate();
        }
        public void removeOverlay(OverlayItem overlay)
        {
            mOverlays.remove(overlay);
            populate();
        }

        @Override
        protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
            return mOverlays.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return mOverlays.size();
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean onTap(int index) {
            OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
            dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
            dialog.show();
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I am giving one solution what I am getting from your question... You need to add Lat Long into Overlay item which is coming from server and add it to itemized overlay, after that when ever you would like to remove any Itemizedoverlay with specific lat long you can check and remove from map overlay as well.